# Formula to find 'Duration Today' in minutes

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

[Pic of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bup4C.png)

There are two columns: 'Start' and 'End'. The 'Duration Column' has the duration between the two in minutes. I need to find 'duration today' in minutes.

For example, let's say today is the 15th. 15th could be in the 'Start' column at times, and in 'End' at times.

If 15th is in the 'start' column, I need to calcuate minutes between the start time and 15th 11:59 pm.
And if 15th is in the 'end' column, I need to calculate minutes between 15th 00:00 am and the end time.

I am trying to do this in Power BI using dax.

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing function that used to calculate the duration in Dax, pretty simple to use it:

```
Duration = DATEDIFF(Sheet1[Start],Sheet1[End],MINUTE)
```

[image]